# jQuery toggleClass not working properly (close div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a button toggle the class of div (sidebar) on click. The class should *close* the sidebar by setting the `max-height` to `130px`.

This is what I have tried so far but for some reason it is not working for me:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.close_sidebar').click(function() {
    $('.sidebar').slideToggle("slow");
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('closed');
    if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('closed')) {
      $('.close_sidebar_text').text('OPEN MAP');
    } else {
      $('.close_sidebar_text').text('CLOSE MAP');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.closed {
  max-height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="close_sidebar" style="border-style:solid; width:70px; height:25px; margin:-5px 0px 0px 647px; cursor:pointer; padding:5px;">
  <div class="close_sidebar_text" style="color:#000; border-style:none; margin:-7px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:12px; font-family: Agency FB;">
    OPEN MAP
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar" style="border-style:none; margin:0px auto 0px; ">
  <div class="searchform" style="color:#000; position:absolute; z-index:1; margin:120px 0px 0px 0px; border-style:none; width:180px; height:200px;">
    <form action="" method="post" id="search">
      <br>
      <select class="selmenu" id="city" name="city" style="border-style:solid; margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;">
        <option value="Novi Sad">Novi Sad</option>
        <option value="Belgrade">Belgrade</option>
        <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input class="txtinput" id="minPrice" name="minPrice" placeholder="Min Price" style=" margin:10px 0px 5px 20px;" type="text">
      <br>
      <input class="txtinput" id="maxPrice" name="maxPrice" placeholder="Max Price" style=" margin:10px 0px 5px 20px;" type="text">
      <br>
      <label for="slika" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 21px; font-size:14px; font-family: Agency FB;">Onlysearch ads with picture</label>
      <input id="slika" name="slika" style=" margin:0px 0px 0px 5px;" type="checkbox">
      <br>
      <input class="submitbtn" style="margin:5px 0px 10px 20px;" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="searchbar">
    <section class="webdesigntuts-workshop">
      <form action="searchpage.php" method="post">
        <input placeholder="Search..." type="search">
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/u5ms2ftu/

Answer (score 0):

The button seems to work fine in my case. Even the jsFiddle link you shared is working fine. On clicking CLOSE MAP button, a class "closed" is getting added to the sidebar div and even the max-height property is added to it.

The visuals that I can see is that after clicking the CLOSE MAP button, the sidebar disappears completely and on clicking OPEN MAP it appears completely. Is it what you want? Or do you want some part of it to be visible and invisible.??
Coz if you want some part of it to go visible and invisible, then you should not use slideToggle for the complete class as it will make the whole class disappear or appear no matter the max-height or min-height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following for this to work:

```
.closed {
  overflow: hidden;
  ...
}
```